# Why are transactions taking so much longer in the last few days (2017-10-29)

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, confirmations

I noticed that in recent blocks there has been lots of transactions that has been waiting for as many as 3 days.

For example, [just randomly picking a block 492200](https://blockchain.info/block/0000000000000000000c76675727edeb8585bb02e4c46ae7f3e8b177d7103f5a), which was produced on 2017-10-29 12:04:50, there are [transactions that date back to 2017-10-26 17:32:41](https://blockchain.info/tx/ff9a41402603c17cb22eb837cd45fa833fcfb0b34c02e820a79b422553bf539e)

However, when I looked at blocks just two weeks ago, there weren't any transaction that were waiting for so long. Again [randomly picking an example block 490200](https://blockchain.info/block/0000000000000000002d74a296b94a363c5cb1406d34b65f0b8a3297abb7813b), produced on 2017-10-16 20:54:59, the [earliest transaction in that block I could find was sent out on 2017-10-16 13:02:04](https://blockchain.info/tx/240a41af0951315941de88f3f12766bec2e99052519a8998c79e6339ba30609e).

So what has happened to the block chain in the past two weeks (except for the Bitcoin Gold fork, but I don't see how that relates to this)?

*Note: I am not asking about how to [solve unconfirmed transactions](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/41972/63081). I am just simply curious what is causing this to happen <del>as block times and network hash power doesn't seem to have changed much</del>.*

Another example: [Transaction is stuck and unspent 2days+](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/61547/63081)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what has happened to the block chain

Some miners moved their hashpower to Bictoin Cash blockchain because it was more profitable for a while. https://cash.coin.dance/blocks

This resulted less hash power on bitcoin main chain and larger intervals between blocks.

Comment: Good answer. Didn't know why I didn't think of that... Surprised by how many miners are actively monitoring the profitability and as a result caused an impact on the network

Comment: The result will be attack-51. While others work on BCC network the dishonest mining pool (alliance) can work on reorganizing bitcoin main chain